# Why is #define throwing "error: expected declaration specifiers"?

Tags: c, openmp, c-preprocessor, c11

I'm new so apologies if my formatting is a little off.
I'm writing a simple OpenMP program in order to get the hang of it, and I've been stopped completely dead in my tracks by a strange compilation error. My serial implementation compiles just fine (with gnu11), but my parallel compilation seems to fail for some reason I can't locate.

The entire code up to the point of failure is as follows (and the error I receive from `make` follows thereafter)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N_THR 1
#define MIN_SIZE 3 //NOTE: min_size is inclusive here
#ifdef _OPENMP
    #include <omp.h>
    #undef N_THR
    #define N_THR 4
    #undef MIN_SIZE
    #define MIN_SIZE N_THR
    //omp_set_dynamic(false); //we need to explicitly disable dynamic teams to force 4 threads
    omp_set_num_threads(N_THR);
#endif
```

```c
gcc maze.c -o maze
gcc maze.c -fopenmp -o mazep
maze.c:11:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
  #define N_THR 4
                ^
maze.c:15:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘N_THR’
  omp_set_num_threads(N_THR);
                      ^~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:5: parallel] Error 1
```

Is there some deep C language syntax hint I'm missing or is it something a little more obvious?

Comment: You can only call a function within another function.  If this line is at "top level" outside any function definition, the compiler tries to parse it as a declaration and fails.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, thanks for the answer! Suppose its time for me to get some rest if I'm forgetting the basics like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are calling `omp_set_num_threads()` outside of a function.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error in this file canCom2.h
in this line

```
#define INST_CANCOM2 (2U)
```

because I had an extra closing curly braces in this file
eeeprom.c

```
} /* extra curly braces*/

#if defined(USING_CAN2) && defined(INST_CANCOM2)
```

After removing the extra curly brace, the error vanished